# How to write spring data mongodb query using dynamic key and dynamic value?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Example of mongo document:

```
contact{
        "id": 7070,
        "name": "test1",
        "email": "test1@yahoo.com",
        "mobile": "+848484848",
        "module": "Test1 Module",
        "otherData": {
            "country": "France",
            "TestProperty1":"test1",
            "TestProperty2":"test2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8080,
        "name": "test2",
        "email": "test2@yahoo.com",
        "mobile": "+000000000000",
        "module": "testmodule2",
        "otherData": {
            "country": "Germany",
            "vip": "Yes"
        }
```

I want to write function using spring data that take a hash map (other data field)as a parameter and return list of contacts that match the map criteria ex. list of contacts that has key 'country' and value 'Germany' and also has key 'vip' and value 'yes'. etc.
I tried this code

```
public List<Contact> getContactByProperties(HashMap properties){
    List<Criteria> searchCriteries=new ArrayList<>();
    properties.forEach((k, v) -> {
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("properties.key").is(k).
                andOperator(Criteria.where("properties.value").is(v));
        searchCriteries.add(criteria);
    });


    Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(searchCriteries.toArray(new Criteria[searchCriteries.size()]));

    Query query = new Query(criteria);

    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Contact.class);
}
```

but it returns
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.lang.String!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have tried any code, please add it to your question.

Comment: I solve it using criteria and mongo template                                                                                   
    List<Criteria> searchCriteries=new ArrayList<>();
        properties.forEach((k, v) -> {
            Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("properties."+k).is(v);
            searchCriteries.add(criteria);
        });
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(searchCriteries.toArray(new Criteria[searchCriteries.size()])); Query query = new Query(criteria);
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Contact.class);

Comment: You can tell about the information you are passing in the `properties` HashMap.